# JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (8:19)

Tags: reactjs, jsx

SyntaxError
/src/components/App.js: JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text (8:19)

What am i doing wrong here?

```
   function noteMap(item) {
      return <Note key=item.key title=item.title content=item.content />
    }
```

[image]

Comment: It's exactly as the error says. The `key`, `title`, etc values need to be either plain text, or enclosed in `{}`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Curly Braces to pass JavaScript values to JSX Component like this  https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx

```
function noteMap(item) {
  return <Note key={item.key} title={item.title} content={item.content} />;
}
```

You can use 2 methods mainly

1. `title = "This is a Title"` => String Method
2. `title = {jsVariable}` => Variable Mathod